# How to use crisp.chat RTM api?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat

I’m trying to authentication and use Crisp.chat rtm api but response of it is 203 and meet No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' .

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io('https://app.relay.crisp.chat/');
```

https://docs.crisp.chat/api/v1/#header-%F0%9F%94%80-rtm-events

Failed to load https://app.relay.crisp.chat/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ml76bvR: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3002' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should use library https://github.com/crisp-im/node-crisp-api
and make a realtime connection with that.
you cant use it in frontend side.